# How to restore default gitlab page?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I mistakenly removed default gitlab page (type of user.gitlab.io/project)
How can I restore this?
Thanks you in advance.

[image]

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief Version:

- Delete repo, repush and wait.

Detailed Version:

1. Keep the repo in your local,
2. Delete repo on gitlab (which will cause losing MR history, but that's not critical for me at least),
3. Create new Repo (no matter it's same name or not)
4. Push the code
5. Then I deleted `.gitlab-ci.yml` as a commit and added it back as another commit, so that you will see "Congratulations! Your pages are served under: https://username.gitlab.io/project-name" in Gitlab Page Setting, (I am not sure this step is required or not, if I am wrong please correct me, it just automatically worked)
6. Then you might still get "404 The page you're looking for could not be found." from that link, what you need to do is just **WAIT**. For me it's about 3 hours (while I am frustrated to looking for other solution, it just worked at some point)

Some explain:

I did step 5 because: it seems gitlab is always automatically enable the default gitlab page once it finds an `.gitlab-ci.yml` file in your repo.